# Rhino Mocks default return type?

Tags: c#-4.0, rhino-mocks

Why does Rhino Mocks(v3.6) generate a proxy type, when the return type is an interface, if you **don't** explicitly specify a return value(I know you should always specify a return, but thats a different issue)?

Many web articles, and even some SO posts [RhinoMock : Mocks Vs StrictMocks Vs DynamicMocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526195/rhinomock-mocks-vs-strictmocks-vs-dynamicmocks), say a mock will return the default type as its result, I'd assume `default(T)`. I'm not seeing this behaviour (see below). I cant find anything on the [Rhino Mocks Documentation](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Documentation.ashx) that specifies the behaviour either.

I've also tested(similar to below) with integral types and a class, as return types, and both of these tests throw an exception *"requires a return value or an exception to throw"*, when I try to call the method, in my Act code. This I dont mind, its obvious whats wrong, and Rhino doesnt 'get creative', though it is inconstant imo.

```
// Arrange
IFoo strictMockInstance = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<IFoo>();
IFoo dynamicMockInstance = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFoo>();

strictMockInstance.Expect(call => call.Bar());
strictMockInstance.Replay();

dynamicMockInstance.Expect(call => call.Bar());
dynamicMockInstance.Replay();

// Act
IResult smResult = strictMockInstance.Bar();
IResult dmResult = dynamicMockInstance.Bar();

// Assert    
Assert.IsNull(smResult); // none of these results are null, both are proxy instances
Assert.IsNull(dmResult);

// ....
public interface IFoo 
{
    IResult Bar();
}

public interface IResult { }
```

Comment: Offtopic, `Expect()/Call()` are not AAA syntaxt which you've mentioned in source code comments, use `AssertWasCalled()` method instead

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason behind this functionality is to support (or handle) hierarchies

Consider the following:

```
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISomeInterface>();
mock.Expect(x => x.Document.Header.CreateRow());
```

When Rhino Mocks comes across a return type that is an interface it will check to see if a mock has already been created. If it does not find one it will create one on the fly to prevent null exceptions