# Rhino-Mocking ExpectationViolationException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I started to use Rhino-Mocks and Unit-Tests a few days ago so I'm new in this.

I created a disposable class like this:

```cs
public class SomeClass : IDisposable
{
    private bool _disposed;

    public SomeOtherClass ObjB { get; private set; }

    public SomeClass(SomeOtherClass b)
    {
        ObjB = b;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            // set all properties to null

            ObjB = null;
            // ...
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

and the unit test which should check if the dispose was done correctly:

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class SomeClassTests
{
    [Test]
    public void ShouldDisposeCorrectly()
    {
        var classB = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<SomeOtherClass>()
        SomeClass smth;

        using (smth = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<SomeClass>(classB))
        { }

        smth.Expect(p => p.ObjB).Should().BeNull();
    }
}
```

Now when I start the test it throws the following error:
***Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException : SomeClass.Dispose(True); Expected #0, Actual #1.***

Can you help me to find the missing step? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you actually wanting to test here?

That the compiler produces the correct code when you use a using statement?  Seems fairly pointeless.

Or that your class implements IDisposable? You could do that with a simpler test.

Or that your disposal routine correctly disposes of the resources? This test doesn't check that. You could completely empty the `Dispose(bool)` method and the test you say you want to write would still pass.

Better to check that `ObjB` is `null` after the object has been disposed and that any other things which should be done in the dispose method have been. What you want to check is that the **behaviour** when you dispose your object is what you expect

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. You are right, it's better to implement a check if the object would be null. Unfortunately the same message appears in this version... I've edited the Unittest part in my question.

Comment: I think you just need to not use a strict mock and instead use a dynamic mock, which won't complain at the lack of explicit setup. See [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526195/rhinomock-mocks-vs-strictmocks-vs-dynamicmocks)